# Binding Width to ActualHeight - only partially working

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-8, width, actualheight

I am trying to bind an image's `Width` to its `ActualHeight` (height is determined by layout and I want it to be square - if there's a better way of doing this, I'd love to hear).

This is my XAML:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Image x:Name="favImage1" Source="{Binding Controller.FailStorage.FailRoamingStorage.Favorites[0].ImageUri}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource FavoriteImageStyle}" Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=favImage1, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</Grid>
```

The style is defined as such:

```
    <Style x:Key="FavoriteImageStyle" TargetType="Image">
        <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="UniformToFill"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,12,12"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
    </Style>
```

Now,this works partially - navigating back to the page after adding items to the collection seems to work.

But any loading, or subsequent navigates to the page make the image to not show.

Interestingly enough, after loading, the image's ActualWidth is NOT the ActualHeight. It's less. And the Grid's width is even less... Which is just plain weird...

> favImage1.ActualWidth
>
> 185.13514709472656
>
> favImage1.ActualHeight
>
> 274.0
>
> ((FrameworkElement)favImage1.Parent).ActualWidth
>
> 138.0

What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Can you set the value of width in some trigger?

Comment: Bind the ActualHeight to a property on the trigger you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you would like to make sure that your image remains square.

I think this is not a right way to manipulate the image in xaml. I would rather wrap the image in a `Border` and set the `Border`'s size to something fix then change the image `Stretch` property to `UniformToFill`:

```
<Border Width="110" Height="110">
    <Image Source="my.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
</Border>
```

Another option is to use the `ViewBox` to wrap the image. Here you can see the effects of the different values for the `Stretch` property:

[ViewBox.Stretch Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.stretch%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That doesn't help me as I need the Height to be set by layout (VerticalAlignment=Stretch on one of the higher elements (I will edit to be more specific). So I can't actually specify any of the dimensions. (Just noticed I did say it at the top of the post: "height is determined by layout and I want it to be square")